# How to spread the values to blank "" within a specific group from another column R

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I have check some similar question give out the approach :
convert blank "" to NA with `na.strings = ("")` > `library(zoo)` > `na.locf()` 
It is not work with a grouping situations like below

```
df <- read.table(header = T,text = 'Int.Index Int.Line Name Index Index.Line Amount
       340        1 John   440          1    700
        NA        2 John   440          2    100
        NA        3 John   400          3     50
       450        1  May   500          1   2401
      5694        1 Paul  6023          1   1312
        NA        2 Paul  6023          2   7244
        NA        1 Tom   7889          1    221
        NA        2 Tom   7889          2   2114
        NA        1 Joe    231          1   1349
      3455        1 Ben   3330          1   1353
        NA        2 Ben   3330          2   8651')
```

**The Target Result**

```
df_result <- read.table(header = T,text = '
    Int.Index Int.Line Name Index Index.Line Amount
       340        1 John   440          1    700
       340        2 John   440          2    100
       340        3 John   400          3     50
       450        1  May   500          1   2401
      5694        1 Paul  6023          1   1312
      5694        2 Paul  6023          2   7244
        NA        1 Tom   7889          1    221
        NA        2 Tom   7889          2   2114
        NA        1 Joe    231          1   1349
      3455        1 Ben   3330          1   1353
      3455        2 Ben   3330          2   8651')
```

Tom group and Joe group between another group without `$Int.Index` will be wrongly spreaded the values which should keep it as Blank "" .
`$Index` representing group and with `$Index.Line` show lines of each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example, we can group by 'Name' and then do the `fill`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
  fill(Int.Index) %>%
  arrange(rn) %>% 
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 11 x 6
# Groups: Name [6]
#   Int.Index Int.Line Name   Index Index.Line Amount
#       <int>    <int> <fctr> <int>      <int>  <int>
# 1       340        1 John     440          1    700
# 2       340        2 John     440          2    100
# 3       340        3 John     400          3     50
# 4       450        1 May      500          1   2401
# 5      5694        1 Paul    6023          1   1312
# 6      5694        2 Paul    6023          2   7244
# 7        NA        1 Tom     7889          1    221
# 8        NA        2 Tom     7889          2   2114
# 9        NA        1 Joe      231          1   1349
#10      3455        1 Ben     3330          1   1353
#11      3455        2 Ben     3330          2   8651
```

NOTE: Using 'Index' as group will categorize the third observation as a separate unit as it is 400 instead of 440.

Comment: Thankyou akrun , 400 was a typo . Perfect answer , thank you so much .